# Restoring node-modules and bower_components based on script contents

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, node-modules

How do I restore node-modules and bower_components?

I want to source control files which are *actually* part of my application and not the dependencies.
I want to restore those dependencies after I clone a fresh copy of my project.
Something like the inverse of *bower wiredep*

Comment: Why cannot you just use something like `npm` and setup a `package.json`? If you can, do that :) You can just run `npm install` after cloning and voila.

Comment: ohh, never knew that. thanks!

Comment: @zackehh how about bower_components? is bower able to do the same?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can just set up a `package.json` for `npm` to install your node_modules using `npm install`. I believe bower also has something similar with `bower.json`.

I think both `npm init` and `bower init` should get you started.

**Edit:** yeah, Bower [has it too](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#bowerjson)

Comment: thanks! i would vote up if i could. but im new here.

Comment: @chutzzz you should be able to accept the answer if you're happy with it :)